# PowerQuery cannot recognize data in filter

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

Dears,

I put some data from PDF files into powerquery. With your help I was able to extract certain phrases (phrases with name starting "23PL...").

Mr Davide Bacci helped me alot.

However for some rows in excel, the data cannot be filtered. When I open second column and put filter "23PL" or "NR FV" or anything from that cell - it is not filtered. PowerQuery doesn't see that cell.
Other cells are filtered just fine.

Do you have any idea why?

[image: example of issue]

[image: Data in row 2, 5 and 8 are not visible in the filter]

Comment: Can  you paste your sample data as copiable text?

Comment: It isn't clear from the screenshot what the issue is - can you also put your expected results.

Comment: The problem is, that when I want to filter the data in the column "B" for example while writing the phrase "MRN: 23PL" - the filter doesn't see that particular phrase.
Filter cannot see any phrase that is included in row  8.

For any other row this issue doesnt appear and I can filter while putting phrases "data dostawy" (row 9)  or "Usługa AC" (row 10) etc., but row 8 is missing in the filter.

These data are being downloaded from pdf invoices and I cannot really share it...

Don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: I just added another screenshot.

Comment: Apologies but this is impossible to debug without actual data.

Comment: Do you need to copy of entire excel with PDF's or the code itself?

Comment: We just need a sample of the data that is causing you the problem along with what your expected result is.

Comment: Before you edit your question to provide more information, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) and also the HELP pages for information as to  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)